# Splitting a pdf file using PDFBOX create huge size files

Tags: java, split, jar, pdfbox

I am working on 1GB PDF file of 75k pages. I have extracted the first 6 pages using PDFBox jar and the size is around 300KB. I would be splitting the document by 6 pages each, that would make the entire storage of these split files to around 3 GB+ . Is there a way around when I am splitting the file to avoid the bloat out of the storage ?

Comment: please share a result file, tell what PDFBox version you're using, and what the result file is for (printing, mailing, archiving?) and whether the result files need to have accessilibity features (for vision impaired people).

Comment: Depending on the pdf in question, splitting can indeed make the sizes explode, e.g. if certain embedded resources (images, fonts) are used in every page, they are present in the original file only once but also in each of the split files. As we don't have your pdf, we cannot tell whether that's the case for you.